# how find view for a custom extended view

Tags: android, classcastexception

I have a class named `CropImageView` which is extended from `ImageView`. but the statement below makes `castException`:

```
CropImageView image = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
```

here is the xml file:

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView  android:id="@+id/image"
                android:background="#55000000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_x="0dip"
                android:layout_y="0dip"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `CropImageView` canonical name in the `XML`. Something like:

```
<your.package.CropImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:background="#55000000"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_x="0dip"
    android:layout_y="0dip"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<com.your.package.CropImageView />` instead of an `<ImageView />` in your layout.